# Linear Regression with chicago crimes dataset possible?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, analysis, lm

iam working with the crimes of chicago dataset from kaggle (this one: https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago) and would like to know if its possible to run a linear regression. I need to do an analysis like LR for my paper, but as I can see the dataset is better for a visualization, which I already did. But is it possible to run a linear regression with this dataset? Like for example: How does the Arrest affect the crime rate or something like this. I hope somebody can help me I am quite new in R and from the structure of the dataset it seems that I cant do that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question. If you need general help with fitting statistical models, you should be asking at [stats.se] where questions about statistics are on topic. Otherwise at least show exactly what you attempted and describe what errors you are getting.

Comment: Is your question on how to do linear regression on R or if it's appropriate to run linear regression with the variables available. If it's the former than you can use the lm function. If it's the latter you should ask of Cross Validated as @MrFlick suggests. If you want to do simple linear regression you could do the lat and long as a function of things like type of crime...

Comment: Well I would like to do a Hierarchical Clustering analysis, but dont know if its possible if my data are just in character formats. I dont have any numeric data. Is it possible with chars? Thanks so much in advance!